# Export PublicKey and PrivateKey from PKCS12 file

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, keystore

I have a .p12 file and I want to export a public and private keys. I used this method:

```
FileInputStream fm = new FileInputStream("C:\\cert.p12");
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    try {
        ks.load(fm, "pass".toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Key key = ks.getKey("cert", "pass".toCharArray());
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("cert");
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    System.out.println("Public key");
    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
            publicKey.getEncoded()));
    fm.close();
```

The second method was to use openssl command and convert it to .cer file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.cer -nodes
```

The third method was to load this cert.cer file to keystore and get key

```
    FileInputStream fm1;
    fm1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\cert.cer");
    CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fm1);
    PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
    System.out.println("Public key");
    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pk.getEncoded()));
```

So my question is why the first public key is the same like in third method but different than in second method. How should i export this key?
thanks for reply

Comment: The second example exports a certificate, not a key.

Comment: Whats the `cert` in `ks.getKey("cert", "pass".toCharArray());`? where can I set/get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, you are reading a PKCS12 type keystore file. In the keystore, one or more private key(s) is inserted. for every private key entry, one certificate or one certificate chain containing many certificates exist. So, here by giving correct alias and keystore password, you are getting Both private key and certificate. And from the certificate, you are getting it's public key 

In the second example, you are getting only certificate from the keystore file. So, here you are not getting public key but the certificate that contains the public key. In order to get the public key from certificate, run following command after your command:

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in certificate.der -pubkey -noout > publickey.pem
```

Now, in the third example, you already have a certificate file to read. You are reading the certificate and get the public key from the certificate.

Hope that, it clears your confusion.

Comment: Do you know why I am getting null value of key for `Key key = ks.getKey("Certificates", "12345678".toCharArray());`? what is this alias for? how can I know what is the value for my `.p12`?