# How to generate JWT token from a valid Certificate.p12 file?

Tags: authentication, push-notification, jwt, apple-push-notifications, keychain

Trying to generate `JWT` for communicating with Apples APNS. Following this [guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1).

`JWT` structure is discussed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=926mknSW9Lo&t=141s), i.e., `HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE`

I have valid Header, Payload and a Certificate `cert.p12` file which I exported from my Keychain on Mac (*created in apple developer portal*). Thus I have now below stuffs with me to create a valid `JWT`,

#### Header:

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "C3P4V6GS95"
}
```

#### Payload:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "iss": "8ABNJK84B2",
  "iat": 1681906661
}
```

#### Signature:

```
valid cert.p12 // exported from Mac keychain.
```

So, how can I get the private and public key from my `cert.p12` which I can use to generate `JWT`?. APNS requires `ES256` which requires `private_key` and `public_key` as [found](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) in jwt.io example.

Comment: are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803335/export-publickey-and-privatekey-from-pkcs12-file ?

Comment: It helps but I am stuck with `ES256` JWT creation. Is there any  java library you know of for spring boot app?

Comment: @jps your referred post's example is returning `null` for key when I call `Key key = ks.getKey("cert", "pass".toCharArray());`

Comment: sorry, can't help. I just found your question title and tags misleading and thought the linked Q/A is what you're really looking for.